# How can I execute code when an entity is being persisted to the database with Entity-Framework code-first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Is there a nice way to execute code when an entity is being saved to the database using EF/code-first?

I have a `Url` property on many of my entities. If a URL has not been given explicitly, I would like to calculate one as the object is persisted, eg.:

```
public void OnModelSaving()
{
    // If a URL has not been specified, generate one from the name.
    if (this.Url == null)
    {
        this.Url = Helper.GenerateSafeUrl(this.Title);
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like all this code to be stored inside the Model, but since I don't have an EF-owned base/partial class, I suspect if it's possible, I'd have to register/wire it up elsewhere. Question is - is it possible, and if so, how do I wire it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to override `SaveChanges` method on your context, iterate through changed entities and check the `Url`

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || 
                                            e.State == EntityState.Modified)
                                .Select(e => e.Entity())
                                .OfType<YourEntityType();

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        entity.Url = ...;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you have many entity types providing `Url` you can try to define interface with that `Url` implemented by all that entity types and in `OfType` use that interface.

Comment: I had a feeling I'd need to do it like that, so I'd already thought about the interface. I think rather than having an interface for the Url stuff, I'll add a generic one that just has an OnModelSaving method so it can be used on any entity for any purpose. Shame it wasn't built in. Thanks!